# JBoss AS7 Management console not displaying

Tags: jboss, fedora

I have install JBoss AS7 on fedora and can run the server by executing

`sudo /usr/share/jboss-as/bin/standalone.sh`

and it starts successfully.

Visiting `http://127.0.0.1:8080/` yields:

> Welcome to AS 7 Your JBoss Application Server 7 is running.

However visiting `http://127.0.0.1:9990/console` yields a blank page.

in the output of `sudo /usr/share/jboss-as/bin/standalone.sh` I can see

```
14:25:53,744 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
```

Does any one have an idea of what is going on?

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same issue with JBoss 7.1.1. I could identify 2 reasons -

1. I hosted the AS7.1 on a Linux server and was trying to access from a separate Win PC. As expected IP addresses were different. `127.0.0.1` would work for the system only. So, I had to change the IP addresses in file `jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml`
2. The port number `9990` was blocked. So, had to change firewall settings of Linux.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Did not use this type of JBoss.
However, my hunch is that you are not accessing the deployed war file of the console: I think you should try something like this: `127.0.0.1:9990/console` or `127.0.0.1:9990/webconsole`

Comment: Thanks, I had already tried `127.0.0.1:9990/console` and just now after seeing this tried `127.0.0.1:9990/webconsole` but still blank page.

Comment: on that welcome page, isn't a link to the console ant to access the console from there? My guess is that you do not try the correct path to the console...:)

Comment: `127.0.0.1:9990/console` is what the home page says is the link.

Answer (score 0):

Add the page to trusted sites. try reopening the page after that you will get the login prompt.

Also make sure you have created a username and password for the ManagementRealm
using adduser command

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem by disabling the protocols filter on the company's endpoint antivirus. Try and look if you have any web threat filter or any protocols filter and disable it/them. Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was localhost showing a blank page when opening the admin console but 127.0.0.1 works just fine. All I did was delete browser cache and data.